# How to send JSON payload Identify on Discord Gateway Websocket

Tags: python, websocket, discord

I'm using this Python code to connect to discord gateway, basically I need to send an Opcode 2 Identify just to be able to send messages on a channel with the Discord API.

```
import websocket
import json
import pprint
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
# Connect to host url
ws.connect("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json")
# Use ws.send() to send data to server
# Use ws.recv() to get the data sent from server
result = ws.recv()
print "Received: ",result
heartbeat = '{"op": 1,"d": 251}'
p = '{"token": "MY_BOT_TOKEN","properties": {"$os": "linux","$browser": "disco","$device": "disco" },"compress": false, "large_threshold": 250,"shard": [0, 1],"presence": {"game": {},"status": "online","since": null,"afk": false}}'
h = json.loads(heartbeat)
h_json = json.dumps(h)
p_load = json.loads(p)
p_json = json.dumps(p_load)
print(h_json)
ws.send(h_json)
# Use ws.close() to close the WebSocket handshake
result = ws.recv()
print "Received: ",result
ws.send(p_json)
result = ws.recv()
print "Received: ",result
```

What this code does is: sending the heartbeat after the op code 10, receive the op code 11 from the server, sends the json object for the opcode 2 identify.

But the result is this:

```
Received:  {"t":null,"s":null,"op":10,"d":{"heartbeat_interval":41250,"_trace":["gateway-prd-main-rskw"]}}
{"d": 251, "op": 1}
Received:  {"t":null,"s":null,"op":11,"d":null}
Received:
```

The problem is that the connection gets closed after sending the json, and I can't receive the response, is there anything wrong in my request?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem at my first try, so I read the documentation carefully and I found the section below.

---

## [Sending Payloads](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#sending-payloads)

**Packets sent from the client to the Gateway API are encapsulated within a gateway payload object and must have the proper opcode and data object set.** The payload object can then be serialized in the format of choice (see ETF/JSON), and sent over the websocket. Payloads to the gateway are limited to a maximum of 4096 bytes sent, going over this will cause a connection termination with error code 4002.

---

#### Ok, what that's mean?

Every packet you sent to Gateway API needs to follow the request model.

```
{
  "op": 0,
  "d": {},
  "s": 42,
  "t": "GATEWAY_EVENT_NAME"
}
```

#### What is each object in this request model?

`op`: The code that tells the Gateway API what is your payload type. You can found the list of `op` [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#gateway-gateway-opcodes).

`d`: The payload itself. Here goes the json your are trying to send (your `p` variable)

`s` and `t`: Only required for `op` 0, so you can pass it as null for `IDENTIFY`.

#### What your request should looks like

```
{
    "op": 2,
    "d": {
        "token": "YOUR_TOKEN_HERE",
        "properties": {
            "$os": "linux",
            "$browser": "disco",
            "$device": "disco"
        }
    },
    "s": null,
    "t": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the heartbeat payload you sent was wrong.

> The **inner d key** is the **last sequence number—s—received by the client.** If you **have not yet received one, send null.**

I am not too sure, but you can try changing the value of `d` to `null`.