# Discord.py gateway connection and disconnects from the API

Tags: python, discord.py, gateway

I've been hosting a discord bot on an online IDE but it happens to disconnect from the API after a while. The code on the IDE continues to run, but on discord, it is unable to respond to commands and essentially the entire bot is completely offline, while a running code is being executed. Even more suprising is a background task that I have assigned to run every minute continues to do it's job ( which is to edit a embed in a server with new information ). I've been going through the documentation and about the gateway kinda stuff but I'm utterly confused. It states that disconnections are regular but never teaches me how to actually connect again rather some snippets of JSON data. Documentation here : `https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents`

I'm a bit new to this stuff but the documentation clearly doesn't talk anything about the way to connect to the gateway, and what to do during a op7 reconnect. How would I be able to incorperate this reconnection thing with my discord bot also?

Comment: There is not code that is causing the problem because I cannot find the code in the first place.

Comment: The problem seems to be that I am unable to find the documentation per the discord python example for gateway connections

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do these help?: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#intents, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.GatewayNotFound, 
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ConnectionClosed, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.ws, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.connect, https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: Not exactly, it's documentation about the gateway but the way to connect and handle the connection is not specified.

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#:~:text=The%20API%20for%20interacting%20with%20Gateways%20is%20complex%20and%20fairly%20unforgiving,%20therefore%20it's%20highly%20recommended%20you%20read%20all%20of%20the%20following%20documentation%20before%20writing%20a%20custom%20implementation.: if I understand it right, you want to implement something on your own to interact with Discord's Gateways.

Comment: Then, these may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769665/discord-bot-connect-websocket-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936450/discord-api-websocket-gateway-connection-disconnects-after-some-time, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790837/how-to-send-json-payload-identify-on-discord-gateway-websocket and https://www.google.com/search?q=gateway+connection+discord.py.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to the websocket while running another bot connecting to the discord API?